# getURL and downfile.file won't download content of webpage (R)

Tags: r, geturl

Currently I am looking into the "getURL" and "download.file" command in R. So far, both worked like a charm.

However, I have problems with one specific link and I don't know why this one doesn't work.

Running

```
getURL
("http://www.r-bloggers.com/improving-script_002-%e2%80%9cmonitor%e2%80%9d/")
```

produce the error:

> Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
>   embedded nul in string: '\037\b'

The "download.file" command creates also a weirdly encoded file:

```
download.file
("http://www.r-bloggers.com/improving-script_002-%e2%80%9cmonitor%e2%80%9d/",
"test.html")
```

Does this work with you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem are the quotes in the URL.  You need to encode it first.  This will work properly.

```
getURL(URLencode("http://www.r-bloggers.com/improving-script_002-%E2%80%9Cmonitor%E2%80%9D/"))
```